# Android: How to make animation starting from the last position?

Tags: android, animation, imagebutton

I have an ImageButton that should change its position depending on the accelerator angle. Unfourtunately, i don't get how to start animation from the last position... Please, help me to understand. I guess, the problem is with RELATIVE_TO_SELF, ABSOLUTE things. Now animation starts in the same place. Thank You in advance :)

```
    public void animateButton (float newAngle) {
    if (animation != null) {
    if (!animation.hasEnded()) {
        return;
    }}

    float goalX = 0f;
    float goalY = 0f;
    if (newAngle == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (newAngle < 0 ) {
        newAngle = Math.abs(newAngle) + 270;
    }


    if ((newAngle > 0) || (newAngle <= 15)) {
        goalX = 0f;
        goalY = - 1f;
    } else if ((newAngle > 15) || (newAngle <= 30)) {
        goalX = - 0.5f;
        goalY = - 0.5f;
    } else if ((newAngle > 30) || (newAngle <= 90)) {
        goalX = - 1f;
        goalY = 0f;
    } else if ((newAngle > 90) || (newAngle <= 180)) {
        goalX = - 0.5f;
        goalY = 0.5f;
    } else if ((newAngle > 180) || (newAngle <= 195)) {
        goalX = 0f;
        goalY = 1f;
    } else if ((newAngle > 195) || (newAngle <= 240)) {
        goalX = 0.5f;
        goalY = 0.5f;
    } else if ((newAngle > 240) || (newAngle <= 300)) {
        goalX = 1f;
        goalY = 0f;
    } else if ((newAngle > 300) || (newAngle < 360)) {
        goalX = 0.5f;
        goalY = - 0.5f;
    } 


animation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, goalX, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, goalY);          
animation.setDuration(1000);
animation.setRepeatCount(1);
animation.setRepeatMode(1);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
ib.startAnimation(animation);       


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `setFillAfter(boolean filled)` not works you can use a [Property](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) animations. They change layout parameters, so you can start animation after she ends from the last position.

Also look [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UbJhmkeSig).